# Run chef block only if chocolatey is installing package

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chocolatey

I'm having an issue with determining if a package was installed or was already installed using chef's chocolatey_package functionality. Pretty much, I'm installing a package that requires an iisreset afterwards. I only want iis to be reset when the package is installed and NOT on subsequent executions of chef-client (where chocolatey will exit early because the package was already installed).

I am storing what packages are being installed in an attributes file. It uses the following format:

```
{'name'=>'blah', 'version'=>'1.0.0'[, 'should_notify'=>'reset iis']}
```

Here's what I have so far, code-wise. How can I modify this to branch based on what action chocolatey performs (install or ?

```
include_recipe 'chocolatey::default'

node['cookbook-name']['choco_packages'].each{ |package|
  chocolatey package['name'] do
  version package['version']
  action :install

  if package.instance_variable_defined?(:@should_notify) && package.should_notify == 'reset iis'
    notify :run, 'execute[reset iis]', :immediately
    end
  end
}

execute 'reset iis' do            
  command 'iisreset'
  action :nothing
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attributes snippet isn't correct, For simplicity, I'll assume it should be:

```
[{ 'name' => 'blah', 'version' => '1.0.0', 'should_notify' => 'restart_iis' }]
```

Chocolatey [shouldn't install the package if it's installed already.](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-cookbook/blob/master/providers/default.rb#L44) So this should work fine:

```
node['cookbook-name']['choco_packages'].each do |package|
  chocolatey package['name'] do
    version package['version']
    notifies :run, "execute[#{package['should_notify']}]"
  end
end

execute 'reset iis' do
  command 'iisreset'
  action :nothing
end
```

Without `:immediately` it will restart IIS **ONCE** at the end of chef run, regardless of number of packages. If you'll add `:immediately`, your IIS will be restarted after each package install.

It won't restart IIS if package is already installed.

Comment: As OP seems to consider the reset optional for some packages, adding `unless package['should_notify'].nil?` or `if package['should_notify'] == 'reset_iis'` at the end of the notify line to avoid notifications if not needed would do.